# Android: Facebook SDK 3.0 - FriendPickerFragment setChecked

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, picker

I'm trying to restore the selected checked friends in a FriendPickerDialog, I tried this before showing fragment but it doesn't help :

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("com.facebook.android.PickerFragment.Selection", "friendId1, friendId2...");
friendPickerFragment = new FriendPickerFragment(args);
```

It looks like FriendPickerFragment's adapter doesn't read the checked GraphUsers property from that bundle parameter..

Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no support for that. File a bug here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and it may be picked up as a feature.